# How to set diffent style to single line graph in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, plot, charts, mpandroidchart

Hello am using [MPAndroiChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for my Android App

I stuck with a requirement where I have to draw a line chart(a single line) with different style. Some part of the line is straight and some part is dotted. Something like this

________...........__________________...______

Is it possible to do in MPAndroidChart?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, call `lineDataSet.enableDashedLine(...)`
Documentation: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/DataSet-classes-in-detail

Comment: Thank you Philipp, it is making the whole series as dashed but I want to mix both the normal line and dashed line which I mentioned in the question. In my requirement part of line which is below some limit should be shown in dashed line and remaining as a normal line. I am looking for such option. please let me know if there are any method to achieve it.

Comment: Use multiple datasets - one dataset with the dashed lines - one with normal

Comment: Hello Philipp, I tired doing the method you suggested but end up creating lot of datasets. Is it possible to set the different colours in single line. I mean I want to show red colour in missing values, like blue to available value and red for missing value. Please suggest on this.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda, It's now 2017 , so any resolution for this question , i am looking for same chat, dashed line and continues line in single chart with single datasets, please suggest can I, i need to display 100 data , First 50 continues line and second 50 data with dashed line. thank you

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I was trying to add multiple datasets, but the problem is with animation, I would like to add step by step animation instead of working in parallel. did you achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple datasets is a litte bit annoying. This is an example with only a dotted part into a line but it means a lot of code (and you have to repeat entries in every series to make it a continous line), and if you need a line becoming dotted and not dotted some times it must be very difficult to solve:

```
 ArrayList<Entry> dataValues2 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<Entry> dataValues3 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ArrayList<Entry> dataValues4 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        
        dataValues2.add(new Entry(0,12));
        dataValues2.add(new Entry(1,10));
        dataValues2.add(new Entry(2,9));
        dataValues2.add(new Entry(3,10));
        dataValues2.add(new Entry(4,9));

        dataValues3.add(new Entry(4,9));//Dotted lines
       dataValues3.add(new Entry(5,8));
        dataValues3.add(new Entry(6,7));
        dataValues3.add(new Entry(7,6));
        dataValues3.add(new Entry(8,5));
        dataValues3.add(new Entry(9,4));
        dataValues3.add(new Entry(10,3));
        dataValues3.add(new Entry(11,5));
        dataValues3.add(new Entry(12,7));
        dataValues3.add(new Entry(13,8));
        dataValues3.add(new Entry(14,10));

        dataValues4.add(new Entry(14,10));
        dataValues4.add(new Entry(15,12));
        dataValues4.add(new Entry(16,11));
        dataValues4.add(new Entry(17,13));
        dataValues4.add(new Entry(18,11));
        dataValues4.add(new Entry(19,14));

        LineChart mpLinechart;
        mpLinechart=findViewById(R.id.linechart);
    
        LineDataSet lineDataSet2=new LineDataSet(dataValues2,"");
        LineDataSet lineDataSet3=new LineDataSet(dataValues3,"");
        LineDataSet lineDataSet4=new LineDataSet(dataValues4,"");

        lineDataSet3.enableDashedLine(12,10,0);
        lineDataSet2.setLineWidth(3f);
        lineDataSet2.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        lineDataSet3.setLineWidth(3f);
        lineDataSet3.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        
        lineDataSet4.setLineWidth(3f);
        lineDataSet4.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets=new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(lineDataSet2);
        dataSets.add(lineDataSet3);
        dataSets.add(lineDataSet4);

        LineData data=new LineData(dataSets);
        mpLinechart.setData(data);

        mpLinechart.invalidate();
```

[Graph with dotted lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdoNl.jpg)