# How to make a dashed line in iOS Charts?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

How do you make a line chart dashed using the nifty [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/charts)? It is done [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011210/how-to-set-diffent-style-to-single-line-graph-in-mpandroidchart) in the Android charts version, but that approach does not work for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Adjust the LineChartDataSet using `.lineDashLenghts`. Example usage below:

```
// Set data to the line chart and format
let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: chartDataArray)
dataSet.lineWidth = 3
dataSet.lineDashLengths = [5]
```

Comment: And you can add more dashes adding more lengths to pattern, something like this - dataSet.lineDashLengths = [5, 1, 9, 3, 4]

Comment: Good call out Denis. For example, doing [5, 15] would give dashes of length 5 and spacing of 15.